# Limiting (clamping) canvas size

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to make moveable world for my HTML game so I put 1600x1200 canvas inside my 800x600 div element and using left and top to move the world. I expected that div will clamp size of my canvas, but instead my canvas overlaps borders of my div. The div doesn't stretch, the canvas is scaled independently from the div.

I tried !important, max-width and max-height, different displays, nothing works. Using CSS for width and height just scales the canvas. I also tried putting my canvas into SVG as foreign object, but I get error "getContext is not a function".

So, how can I limit size of my canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` is going to expand to the size of your `canvas` unless the `div` has `overflow: hidden;` set in its CSS. The child element is larger than the parent element, and you haven't strictly told the browser to limit the sizing of the parent element.

The `max-width` and `max-height` attributes won't help you here because you aren't placing "wrappable" content within the `div`. If you put text in a `div` with `max-width` set, the value will be respected. If you put an element with an unchanging size, like an `image` or a `canvas` element, the browser can't dynamically wrap it like a bunch of floating `divs` or some text. In this case, you have `overflow`, which needs to be handled differently.

You can achieve what you're looking for by playing with the `position` and/or `margin` attributes for the `canvas` element once you set the parent `div` to hide the overflow.